# Accuracy hit in classification with naive Bayes MlLib

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, bigdata, mahout, apache-spark-mllib

I had been using Mahout's 0.9 Naive Bayes algorithm to classify document data. For a specific train(2/3 of data) and test (1/3 of data) set, I was getting accuracy in the range of 86%. When I shifted to Spark's MLlib, the accuracy dropped to 82%. In both case using Standard Analyzer.

MlLib Link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-naive-bayes.html 
Mahout link: http://mahout.apache.org/users/classification/bayesian.html

Please help me in this regard as I have to use Spark in a production system very soon and this is a blocker for me.

I found a problem also MlLib take more time in data classification compare to Mahout.

And can any one help for me increase accuracy using MlLib naive Bayes.

Comment: Are you sure this is an apples-to-applies comparison? same normalization, priors, etc?

Comment: And also try to this data set http://people.csail.mit.edu/jrennie/20Newsgroups/20news-bydate.tar.gz  , Naive bayes MlLib give accuracy 72%.

Comment: I am following all steps of the below given example. It uses Lucene to find relevant terms in the document which I use to create TFIDF vectors. Can you please verify if this is the correct way. http://chimpler.wordpress.com/2014/06/11/classifiying-documents-using-naive-bayes-on-apache-spark-mllib/